# Toggle USB Audio on Android

Tags: android, audio, xamarin.android, android-5.0-lollipop

Android Lollipop now supports USB Audio out of the box.  However, I would like to be able to control audio routing to the USB audio device.  Is there any method in the Android SDK that will allow this degree of control?  I tried using setForceUse, but that is inconsistent across devices, and only seems to work for when a USB Audio device is not connected (not to mention there is no USB option for setForceUse).

For example, I would like my app to be able to play to the normal cellphone headphone jack, but with a toggle button be able to route that same audio to the connected USB Audio device.  Another press of the toggle button would switch back to the headphone jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can fake out whether the headphone jack is plugged in by calling setDeviceConnectionState and specifying that the headphone/headset are either available (which will play through the headphone) or unavailable (which will play through USB).  This will toggle the USB audio, which is what I set out to do.  There may be a cleaner method but this works for now.

```
audioSystemClass = Class.ForName("android.media.AudioSystem");

// will disable the headphone
setDeviceConnectionState.Invoke(audioSystemClass, (Java.Lang.Integer)DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADPHONE, (Java.Lang.Integer)DEVICE_STATE_UNAVAILABLE, new Java.Lang.String(""));

// will enable the headphone
setDeviceConnectionState.Invoke(audioSystemClass, (Java.Lang.Integer)DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADPHONE, (Java.Lang.Integer)DEVICE_STATE_AVAILABLE, new Java.Lang.String(""));
```